# rails, slim and form_tag does not allow more then one on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

I am using slim templates for my rails application. But something strang is happening. In my application template I have a form like so:

```
= form_tag search_path, class:'navbar-search pull-left', remote: true
= text_field_tag :term, nil, class: 'search-query span2', placeholder: 'Search'
```

That renders well on my page and the search form is working fine. However in my sign up partial I have:

```
= form_tag '/auth/identity/callback'
        - if @identity && @identity.errors.any?
        div.error
            h2 =pluralize(@identity.errors.count, 'error')
            |prohibited this account from being saved:
            ul
                - @identity.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    li =msg
    h1
        i.iconbig-lock
        | Sign In
    div.login-fields
        p Sign In using your email:
        div.field
            = label_tag :auth_key, 'Email'
            = text_field_tag :auth_key, nil, class: 'input login username-field', placeholder: 'Email'
        div.field
            = label_tag :password, 'Password'
            = password_field_tag :password, nil, class:'login password-field', placeholder: 'password'
        div.login-actions
            = submit_tag 'Login', class: 'btn-signin btn btn-primary'
        div.login-social.marg10-btm
            p Sign in using social network:
            a.btn
                = image_tag 'twitter-18.png'
                |  Signin with twitter
            a.btn href="/auth/facebook"
                = image_tag 'facebook-18.png'
                |  Signin with Facebook
```

the form tag doesn't render, but all sub elements text fields (including the 'authenticity_token') renders fine.

I play around abit and notice that the page only allow 1 form_tag. Ones created after the first never renders. I been looking on google for a while and could not figure why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

from [leogalmeida @ github](https://github.com/leogalmeida/slim-rails/issues/23)

> Try adding 'do' in the end of both form tags:

```
= form_tag search_path, class:'navbar-search pull-left', remote: true do

= form_tag '/auth/identity/callback' do
```